# Wordpress, how to get the tag slug from tag name in a post page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a single post, how to get the tag slug & tag id of tag used for that particular post.

For e.g; I have a post "Hello World!" tagged in "My Post". How to get the slug "my-post" in "Hello World!" post page(i.e; single.php file).

Comment: try get_term_by("My Post"),var_dump it and you may get some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
    // get the first term
    $term = array_shift( $terms );
    echo $term->slug;
}
```

Reference : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130947/get-term-slug-of-current-post

Comment: @DurgaPrasadKundu, i guess now you can. :-)